# RegEx----What is mean "?!:"?

Tags: regex

[codes image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEI0r.png)
If the question: Will the regular expression "?!:" What does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a "Negative Lookahead Assertion".  This code is saying "this regular expression matches only if it begins with `/wiki/` and is not followed by a colon".

Consider reading through https://www.regular-expressions.info and in particular the [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Answer (score -2):

```
? --> zero or one occurrences of the previous expression
! --> negation
: --> simple colon
```

So... it would mean 'zero or one occurrences of the previous expression, not followed by a colon'